# XslCompiledTransform: attribute values incorrectly encoded

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm using `XslCompiledTranform` to transform XML/XSL.

This is my test XSL:

```
<span title="{./tooltip}" anattribute="{./tooltip}">
<xsl:value-of select="./tooltip"/>
</span>
```

You can see that for testing I put the same XSL value, namely `@tooltip` into the `title` attribute, an undefined `anattribute` attribute and also as text into the node.

In my XML the `@tooltip` is encoded like this "`this is a &lt;script&gt; tag`". To be more precise: there are no HTML tags in the value. Everything is encoded, hence the `&lt;` and `&gt;`

If I transform the above I get as result:

```
<span title="this is a <script> tag" anattribute="this is a <script> tag">
this is a &lt;script&gt; tag
</span>
```

Why is keeping the encoding for node values and why is it substituting the encoded values for attributes? And most important: how can I stop `XslCompiledTransform` from behaving like that? I want my attributes **exactly** the way I specified them and no magic conversion going on.

My settings are as follows:

```
var oXSL = new XslCompiledTransform( );
XsltSettings oXslSettings = new XsltSettings( );
XmlUrlResolver oUriResolver = new XmlUrlResolver( );
oXslSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;
oXslSettings.EnableScript = false;
oXSL.Load( sXslPath, oXslSettings, oUriResolver );
```

René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The html output method should not escape < characters occurring in
>   attribute values.

For more information read spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method

Use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`

Input XML:

```
<root>
    <tooltip>this is a &lt;script&gt; tag</tooltip>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <span title="{tooltip}" anattribute="{tooltip}">
            <xsl:value-of select="tooltip"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

C# source code:

```
var oXSL = new XslCompiledTransform();
XsltSettings oXslSettings = new XsltSettings();
XmlUrlResolver oUriResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
oXslSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = true;
oXslSettings.EnableScript = false;
oXSL.Load(@"1.xslt", oXslSettings, oUriResolver);    
oXSL.Transform(@"input.xml", @"output.xml");
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<span title="this is a &lt;script&gt; tag" anattribute="this is a &lt;script&gt; tag">this is a &lt;script&gt; tag</span>
```

Comment: What I see from your example is that you output method="xml". That's different. Mine is method="html". But in both, < would be invalid in an attribute. Where the hell is my < and > then coming from?

Comment: I tried it. It really is the output="html" that breaks it. It works with output="xml". So thanks for the answer, but WHY?

Comment: @Krumelur, Than use `output method="xml"`. What's the problem?

Comment: @Krumelur, That's because `<span title="Hello, <world>!"></span>` it is valid HTML.

Comment: How is that valid HTML? Really? Does not look like it at all.
The problem I have with "xml" is that my site just stops rendering. I get script errors left and right, page is empty.